# Keyed service dependency problem when injecting in Program.cs

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mediatr

I wrote a interface and implemented it in 3 services, but when I used `AddKeyedScoped` to inject these to project I get the following error.

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: This service descriptor is keyed. Your service provider may not support keyed services.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor.ThrowKeyedDescriptor()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor.get_ImplementationType()
   at MediatR.Registration.ServiceRegistrar.<>c.<RegisterBehaviorIfImplementationsExist>b__12_0(ServiceDescriptor service)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.OfTypeIterator[TResult](IEnumerable source)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at MediatR.Registration.ServiceRegistrar.RegisterBehaviorIfImplementationsExist(IServiceCollection services, Type behaviorType, Type subBehaviorType)
   at MediatR.Registration.ServiceRegistrar.AddRequiredServices(IServiceCollection services, MediatRServiceConfiguration serviceConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMediatR(IServiceCollection services, MediatRServiceConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMediatR(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configuration)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\Soshyant\farabixo-middlewares\src\FarabixoMiddleware\Program.cs:line 51
```

Code:

```cs
services.AddKeyedScoped<IEPaymentService, SamanService>(BackofficeOptions.SamanBankService);
services.AddKeyedScoped<IEPaymentService, MellatService>(BackofficeOptions.MellatBankService);
services.AddKeyedScoped<IEPaymentService, MelliService>(BackofficeOptions.MelliBankService);
```

Comment: Do you have a full [mre]? Can you please share it (for example post somewhere @github if it is too big)?

Comment: @GuruStron Do not ask for code to be posted on Github. That is against the rules of Stack Overflow, which explicitly state that code must be wholly contained in the question itself.

Comment: The exception shows that MediatR is used. [MediatR doesn't support keyed services.](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/942) but the latest version [should exclude them](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/88c4d73ce514a64a9083aeb8df2e2c3692049b7d/src/MediatR/Registration/ServiceRegistrar.cs#L273)  instead of throwing. Please post the actual code that threw the exception

Comment: In any case you'll have to modify your code either not require keyed services or use a factory method/class. Eg a `PaymentPicker(ServiceProvider services)` service with a method `public IEPaymentService Get(string key)=>services.GetRequiredKeyedServices<IEPaymentService>(key);`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
 Thanks. You right this is MediatR exeption. for solve this i'm write a factory method based on your Opinion.